# Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM + mod_fastcgi (Problems setting up PHP-FPM)

Tags: php, php-fpm, fastcgi, apache-2.4, mod-fastcgi

I have been trying to get PHP-FPM to work with Apache 2.4, but mod_fastcgi does not work with 2.4. Is there any solution to this problem? I want to run it using an UNIX socket, but I cannot find any tutorial on this, they all use 127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: You should expand on the exact problem you have

Answer (score 1):

I installed Apache 2.2 with mod_fastcgi and it works using UNIX sockets.

Snippet of configuration from my httpd.conf is:

```
<IfDefine FASTCGI>
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        Alias                   /php5.fastcgi /var/www/example.com/cgi-bin/php5.fastcgi
        FastCGIExternalServer   /var/www/example.com/cgi-bin/php5.fastcgi -flush -socket /var/www/example.com/php-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 30
        AddType                 application/x-httpd-fastphp5    .php
        Action                  application/x-httpd-fastphp5    /php5.fastcgi

        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>
</IfDefine>
```

PHP-FPM is listening on socket /var/www/example.com/php-fpm.sock.

PHP-FPM's configuration (inside a pool):

```
listen          = /var/www/$pool/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner    = apache
listen.group    = apache
listen.mode     = 0660
```

I did not succeed with mod_fcgi. Apache 2.4 now has mod_proxy_fcgi which I didn't tested. You need something with that can work with external FastCGI servers and don't manage the processes itself.

Comment: I would suggest to be more restrictive on file extensions to avoid injection attacks such as **malicious.php.jpg**. Replace `AddType` with `<FilesMatch \.php$> SetHandler application/x-httpd-fastphp5 </FilesMatch>`

Comment: Nevermind. There is a PHP-FPM configuration option `security.limit_extensions` that has a default value of `.php` which does exactly the same. (Well, maybe not *exactly* the same.)

Comment: Still, it's worth checking. I will check both, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for mod_fastcgi that compiles against Apache 2.4: [ByteInternet / libapache-mod-fastcgi](https://github.com/ByteInternet/libapache-mod-fastcgi)
(Currently, the tag **byte/2.4.6-1byte6+apache24** and the branch **byte** include this patch.)

Before you compile the module with `apxs` apply the following patch:

```
patch --input=debian/patches/byte-compile-against-apache24.diff
```

Then compile / install / activate:

```
apxs -ciao mod_fastcgi.so *.c
```